# Visualizing lists of dictionaries as a datagrid in LinqPAD?

Tags: c#, dictionary, visualization, linqpad

I love the might of the `.Dump()` extension method in LinqPAD and would like to use it to visualize a list of `Dictionary<string,string>` as a data grid, where the keys are column names and values are single values respectively.

Basically what I want to achieve is:

[image: Table Visualisation]

instead of (currently getting)

[image: Dictionary entries]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a DataTable which should display in both modes correctly.

With an extension method like

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,T>> source)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable(); 
    foreach(var dict in source)
    {
        var dr = table.NewRow();
        foreach(var entry in dict)
        {
            if (!table.Columns.Contains(entry.Key))
                table.Columns.Add(entry.Key, typeof(T));
            dr[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
        }
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return table;       
}
```

you can then do something like

```
 listOfDictionaries.ToDataTable().Dump();
```

Answer (score 10):

You can get this by turning them into `ExpandoObjects`:

```
listOfDictionaries.Select(x => x.ToExpando()).ToList().Dump();


public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this IDictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    var expando = new ExpandoObject();
    var expandoDic = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
    foreach (var kvp in dict)
        expandoDic.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    return expando;
}
```

[image: List<ExpandoObject> with two columns: "one" and "two"]

Comment: This is the best result I can get so far, thanks. The only problem with the solution is that if you use `Results to DataGrid` option then you can't get the datagrid, rather the set of items...

Answer (score 2):

how about just

```
listOfDictionaries.Select(d => new { One = d["one"], Two = d["two"] })
```

Comment: Yes, and I did it to produce the first picture, but I don't want to change this conversion method every time my keys (e.g. columns of my table) change.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct way to influence the column names: according to [LinqFAQ](http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx) one has to implement `LINQPad.ICustomMembershipProvider`.

For `Dictionary<string,string>` with `Keys` being column names and `Values` actual values one just has to add the following code  to `My Extesions`:

```
public class KVEntry : Dictionary<string,string>, LINQPad.ICustomMemberProvider
{
    IEnumerable<string> ICustomMemberProvider.GetNames() 
    {
        return Keys;
    }

    IEnumerable<Type> ICustomMemberProvider.GetTypes()
    {
        return Enumerable
                .Repeat(typeof(string),Count);
    }

    IEnumerable<object> ICustomMemberProvider.GetValues()
    {
        return Values;
    } 

    public KVEntry(Dictionary<string,string> data) : base(data){}
}
```

Now one has to use `KVEntry` instead of `Dictionary<string,string>` in LINQPad queries. This allows me to correctly render my objects and the grid can even be exported to Excel.

[image: Correct Grid]

**Unfortunately,** this doesn't work for `Results to Data Grids` mode, where LINQPad (probably by design) just ignores the `ICustomMemberProvider` altogether.